# Wordpress home page not recognized

Tags: wordpress, rename

I was having an issue with one of my Wordpress websites. I had used a homepage place holder and worked on the rest of the site. I attempted to delete the placeholder homepage and renamed the new “home” page. The new home page doesn’t seem to be recognized and I need to add “/home/“ to the end of the site name.

I’m not sure what I am doing wrong.

I thought that renaming or rebuilding a "home" page would have the newly named "home" page be recognized. Similar to naming an html page "index". That doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reading settings, place your new home page like static.